# Starting Azure webrole in Visual studio 2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I migrating project to Azure sdk 2.2 and new Visual studio

In full emulator webrole starts long time. At first I thought that it didn't start. But happened to notice that after 15 minutes it starts and works fine.

In emulator of VS 2012 it works fine.

In deploy it works fine.

In express emulator of VS 2013 it works fine too.

Someone has Any ideas, how I can find a solution for startup time in emulator from VS 2013?

Update: I found a problem. In VS2013 discontinued Visual Studio Development Server and I need to configure Full IIS

Comment: Any errors or error output?  Any suspicious entries in the EventLog?

Comment: No.
Problem was in the IIS settings. We used the Visual Studio Development Server before, but in the new VS is no longer available.
Now we just use IIS Express :)
Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, good to know!